# Which reverse ajax library for Java?

Tags: java, web-applications, comet, reverse-ajax

What are worth to look at libraries for reverse ajax in Java web app?

`Atmopshere` is still in 0.6 version, `ICEpush` still in alpha version, and websockets in Firefox 4.0 wont be available too.

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't sound like you are using App Engine, but they provide a Channel API.

Answer (score 3):

Try out [Comet with Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/WhatIsComet).  Also, Tomcat 7 might be useful to you since it implements the Servlet 3.0 spec, which I believe has some niceties for Reverse Ajax thanks to the Async support.  [Here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html?page=3) is an example.

Answer (score 2):

Try [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use APE(Ajax Push Engine). Here is the link [**APE**](http://www.ape-project.org/demos.html)

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about atmosphere is that it delegates to the best underlying mechanism available, and these mechanisms are mostly stable (each container provides its own ways). I think it's more or less a standard solution, so don't be bothered by the version. (Note: I haven't used it)

Answer (score 0):

The blog post [Introduction to Comet and Reverse AJAX](http://www.javabeat.net/introduction-to-comet-and-reverse-ajax/#sthash.yLn6M5bd.dpuf) by Krishna Srinivasan says:

> **AJAX push with ICEfaces**
>
> It is an open source AJAX based framework for developing Rich Internet Applications using Java. AJAX push is an exciting feature of ICEfaces which enable us to develop Comet web application with simple Java API without worrying about the low-level details of the push-mechanism. ICEfaces uses “long polling” to communicate from server to client. This involves holding an open connection from client to server with a blocking request, and then sends the response only when some state change in the application.